# Instagram: how to get the info of a single picture?

Tags: php, instagram

I have a page that shows the latest 50 pics of a certain #hashtag.

I'd like the user to click on the image and go to a page, of the same website, where I can show the full size pic, the title ....

I've searched a lot but I cannot find a way to get the info of a single picture.
Something like this: http://snapwidget.com/view/?id=273145283494542941_10884350#.UE9ukhhwPw8

Thank you!

Comment: in the future, explain what you've tried so far! But check out my answer for some info.

Comment: you might want to accept the answer to help others out.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/)?

You can use:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/MEDIA-ID?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

to get the info I've passed the image id in a `$_GET` variable... Something like this:

`http://yoursite.com/image.php?id=3`

```
<?php
//image.php

     $image = $_GET['id'];

     $info = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/'.$image.'?access_token='.$token;

     $response = json_decode($info, true);

     //example for full size image
     $fullsize = $response['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];

     echo '<img src="'.$fullsize.'"/>';

?>
```

**EDIT: also have a look at [THIS](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API), it's a PHP wrapper for Instagram, very useful!**

Comment: Thank you tdun! this is very very useful. I've looked at the Instagram API, but I've not found this.

I still don't understand this:

when I decode the JSON data from a request like this:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/soccer/media/recent/?access_token=000000

Where is the MEDIA-ID? I mean, how can I get the id of your example: 

http://yoursite.com/image.php?id=3

THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I GOT IT!!!

foreach ($jsonData->data as $key=>$value) { echo $value->id ; }

This simple stuff works: $value->id

Thank you for your great help!!!!!

Thank you, thank you and thank you!!!!

Comment: @Matt no problem! sorry for the late response, but I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: @Matt you can accept this answer and vote it up to give me credit and help others :)

Comment: @Matt you can still accept the answer to help other users that find this question!

Answer (score 0):

I use the shortcode:

From the imgage url, I get the shortcode: eg.: https://instagram.com/p/2rqCzTTdUX/  -> 2rqCzTTdUX

Then, with the following endpoint:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/{shortcode}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

I get the same data as with the media/{media_id} api. Then, I look for the param 'id' at top level
of data (in the json api's response) -> '985065853803556759_429959980'

Finally, for example, I can use the api get media:
v1/media/{media_id}?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN